# Python: How to replace values in an array by values of another array if smaller than?

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare two lists and replace the values of the first one by the values of the second one only if they are smaller.

I tried the smaller than function from python but this seems to replace the whole list.

```py
A = [7 , 10 , 2, 5 , 9]
B = [8 , 12 , 1, 4 , 7]

A[A < B] = B
```

This replaces list A by list B, probably because it compares the whole list. I would want only the values replaced that are smaller than the ones in B resulting in:

[8 , 12 , 2 , 5 , 9]

Comment: Are you sure that `A[A<B] = B` doesn't just assign `B` to `A[1]`?

Comment: What does this have to do with numpy? If you're using numpy, please show a proper example.

Comment: Yes, it completely replaces A. About the numpy that was a mistake, sorry.

Comment: I've added a non numpy solution if you want to avoid the import

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([7, 10, 2, 5, 9])
B = np.array([8, 12, 1, 4, 7])

A[A < B] = B[A < B]
print(A)
```

**Output**

```
[ 8 12  2  5  9]
```

Comment: This looks like the right answer. However, when I try this the firs number of A stays a 7.

Comment: @Michiel I cannot reproduce, I ran this on my computer and gives the same output as in the answer. What numpy version are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.13.3. Found my mistake, I forgot to add np.array.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

With [`numpy.place`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html) - to change elements of an array in-place based on conditional:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([7 , 10 , 2, 5 , 9])
b = np.array([8 , 12 , 1, 4 , 7])
np.place(a, a < b, b)
print(a)    # [ 8 12  2  5  9]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep this in vanilla python, you can do something like:

```
A[:] = [max(a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

This does a true in-place operation, such that `id(A)` does not change. A simpler approach might be to just reassign `A`:

```
A = [max(a, b) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```